# jquery validation in multiple forms

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, validation

I have a form with the following format:

```
<form id="program" name="program method="get" action="process.jsp">

<div id="add">
some input box here...........
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Add">

</div>

<div id="exit">
some input box here...........
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Exit">

</div>

<div id="refuse">
some input box here...........     
<input type="submit" name="action" value="Refuse">

</div>

</form>
```

My jquery code validation is:

```
$("#program").validate({
          errorClass: "error",
          rules: {
       doentry: {
           required: true,
           date: true
       },
       doe: {
           required: true,
           date: true
       },
       dor: {
           required: true,
           date: true
       },
       cid: {
           selectNone: true
            }
         }
            });
```

where dor, doe, doentry is an `<input>` that is in different div, the problem is when I click on submit, on a div that is currently visible (not hidden), it requires all the other elements in the other div's that is currently hidden to be validated as well... which I don't want! What's the best way to solve this just by modifying the jQuery.. ***so only it validates the elements that is inside a div that is currently visible and not the whole form***.

Comment: You're aware of the [`fieldset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-structure) and [`label`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL) elements, right?

Comment: Ehmm...so you mean instead of div's I should use fieldset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation plugin has an [`ignore` option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), use that with the [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector to ignore elements that aren't visible, like this:

```
$("#program").validate({
      ignore: ":hidden",
      errorClass: "error",
      //rules, etc..
});
```

Comment: are you missing a closing quote on the hidden?

Comment: @EquinoX - oops, indeed I was, fixed!